# TypeError int and funcs

Tags: python, optimization, typeerror, knapsack-problem

hello guys I'm trying to write code for an optimization problem in python, the problem is I need to heal a person with medicine, medicine1 heals 25 units requires 3 herb A and 2 herb B and medicine2 heals 20 units requires 4 herb A and 1 herb B.I have 25 units of herb A and 10 units of herb B. in the end I want to print the maximum health that I can heal and how many of each medicines 1 and 2 that I used(clearly had no idea how to put it)

I tried to write a knapsack problem but I keep getting the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'

```
med1= 25
med2= 20
x=25
y=10
health=0
def knapsack(health,med1,med2,x,y):
    if x==0 or y==0:
        return knapsack
    if(med1+knapsack(health+med1,med1,med2,x-3,y- 
   2)>med2+knapsack(health+med2,med1,med2,x-4,y-1)):
        return (med1+knapsack(health+med1,med1,med2,x-3,y-2))
    else:
        return (med2+knapsack(health+med2,med1,med2,x-4,y-1))
print(knapsack(health,med1,med2,x,y))
```

Can someone help me.
Thanks

Comment: You don't set `med1` anywhere before passing it as an argument to `knapsack`. You probably want to use `<-` instead of `==` when checking `x` and `y`. And `return knapsack` is returning the function itself, not an integer.

Comment: `return (med1[0]+knapsack(health+med1[0],med1,med2,x-3,y-2))` and this line `return (med2[0]+knapsack(health+med2[0],med1,med2,x-4,y-1))` - for this recursion to work you eventually need to have knapsack return a int (assuming med1[0] is an int.  Instead your base case `if x==0 or y==0:
        return knapsack` returns the function.  So you end up with med1[0], an int, + a function, which python does not know how to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning inconsistent values from your `knapsack()` function, esp line:

```
return knapsack
```

is causing you problems as this returns callable but you want the integer value
as further lines (recursively invked) do

```
return (med1[0]+knapsack(health+med1[0],med1,med2,x-3,y-2))
```

which then turns into (you got too many brackets btw):

```
return int + callable
```

and then your code fails. So this is either incomplete code, or you copy-paste it from somewhere w/o reading.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that `return knapsack` is returning the function itself, not an integer, which is why you're getting the TypeError. What you want to return, if I'm reading your code correctly, is the unchanged value of `health` (since you won't be using any medicine).

Here is a much simpler way to do it, using plain integers rather than single-element lists for `med1` and `med2`, and the built-in function [*max()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), which returns the larger of two values passed to it:

```
def knapsack(health,med1,med2,x,y):
    if x <= 0 or y <= 0:
        return health
    return max(med1+knapsack(health+med1, med1, med2, x-3, y-2),
               med2+knapsack(health+med2, med1, med2, x-4, y-1))

print(knapsack(0, 25, 10, 25, 10))
```